# filter long string and put results into array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

Trying to create a function whereby you have 2 filters, vb then goes through a long string of text, finds all the text between the 2 filters and stores each result in an array.

So if I have the following in a text file:

```
<Webpage>Hello</Webpage>
SOME_RANDOM_TEXT
<Webpage>There</Webpage>
SOME_RANDOM_TEXT
<Webpage>Testing</Webpage>
SOME_RANDOM_TEXT
<Webpage>Some</Webpage>
SOME_RANDOM_TEXT
<Webpage>Code</Webpage>

Filter 1 = <Webpage>
Filter 2 = </Webpage>
```

<strike>For some reason the Stackoverflow webpage won't allow me to add "<" or ">" to the filters, it just clears the text but you get the idea for what the 2 filters would be.</strike>

I would then want vb to go through the entire page of text and return each of the words and store them in an array like:

```
Array1(Hello)
Array2(There)
Array3(Testing)
Array4(Some)
Array5(Code)
```

Currently I'm doing the below which gives me an error of "Argument 'Length' must be greater or equal to zero.", however if the result only appears once throughout the text file it returns that ok, seems to not be working because there's multiple results returned.

```
Dim TrackNameSource As String = ReadFile 'String that is being searched
    Dim TrackNameDelimStart As String = "<Webpage>" 'First delimiting word
    MsgBox(TrackNameDelimStart)
    Dim TrackNameDelimEnd As String = "</Webpage>" 'Second delimiting word
    MsgBox(TrackNameDelimEnd)
    Dim TrackNameIndexStart As Integer = TrackNameSource.IndexOf(TrackNameDelimStart) 'Find the first occurrence of f1
    Dim TrackNameIndexEnd As Integer = TrackNameSource.IndexOf(TrackNameDelimEnd) 'Find the first occurrence of f2

    If TrackNameIndexStart > -1 AndAlso TrackNameIndexEnd > -1 Then '-1 means the word was not found.
        Dim TrackNameString As String = Strings.Mid(TrackNameSource, TrackNameIndexStart + TrackNameDelimStart.Length + 1, TrackNameIndexEnd - TrackNameIndexStart - TrackNameDelimStart.Length) 'Crop the text between
        MsgBox(TrackNameString)
    End If
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Approach if you are reading in file line by line.

"filepath" is the full path to where file is on your fs.

Only thing left to consider now is if you have multiple Anchor tags in the same line.

```
Dim pos1 As Integer
Dim pos2 As Integer
Dim Str1 As String
Dim Str2 As String  
Dim Line As String

Open "<filepath>" For Input As #1

Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, Line

            filter1 = InStr(Line, "<Webpage>")
            filter2 = InStr(Line, "</Webpage>")

            If filter1 > 0 And filter2 > 0 Then
            Str1 = Left(Line, filter2 - 1)

            filter3 = InStr(Str1, "<Webpage>")
            Str2 = Mid(Str1, filter3 + 9, Len(Str1))

            ' add Str2 to array

    End If
Loop
Close #1
```

Comment: Thanks Jesse, at the moment I've essentially downloaded a webpage which i've then read into a string called "ReadFile", it's after this point at which I'm getting lost on how to handle it.

I tried what you said but pos1 and 2 and unused and the second cell value, the second "1" is throwing a too many arguments error.

Comment: Ahh sorry, I see now, so you've read it in as a single string. Honestly you will be spending a lot of time coming up with an algorithm if you are treating the entire page as a single string. I would recommend downloading the page to a file and reading it in line by line. Just to reduce the complexity for you. This will also nullify proposed solution, as you could have nested tags.

Comment: In sed I would use "sed -n "s/.*SOMEVALUE\(.*\)ANOTHERVALUE.*/\1/p" which would print all occurences between the 2 values, that's what I'm trying to do in VB essentially.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Dim text As String = "<Webpage>Hello</Webpage>SOME_RANDOM_TEXT<Webpage>There</Webpage>SOME_RANDOM_TEXT<Webpage>Testing</Webpage>SOME_RANDOM_TEXT<Webpage>Some</Webpage>SOME_RANDOM_TEXT<Webpage>Code</Webpage>"
    Dim filterStart As String = "<Webpage>"
    Dim filterEnd As String = "</Webpage>"
    Dim words As New List(Of String)

    Do While True
        If text.Length = 0 Then
            Exit Do
        End If

        Dim index as Integer = text.IndexOf(filterStart)

        If index > -1 Then
            text = text.Substring(index + 9)
            index = text.IndexOf(filterEnd)
            Dim word As String
            if index > -1 Then
                word = text.Substring(0, index)
                words.Add(word)
                text = text.Substring(index + 10)
            Else
                word = text 
                words.Add(word)
                Exit Do
            End If
        Else
            Exit Do
        End If

    Loop
```